# Trying to get an average in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I'm trying to get the average retail price of books by publisher name and category. I only want to include the categories 'CHILDREN' and 'COMPUTER' and the groups with an average retail price greater than $50. I'm stuck!

```
SELECT PUBLISHER.NAME, BOOKS.CATEGORY
  TO_CHAR(AVG(BOOKS.RETAIL), '99.99') "Avg Retail"
FROM BOOKS, PUBLISHER
WHERE BOOKS.category='CHILDREN' or BOOKS.category='COMPUTER' and AVG > 50;
```

Comment: You have a Cartesian join of `BOOKS` and `PUBLISHER`. You have to figure our the correct way to join these tables.

Comment: Search for `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, there are plenty of tutorials and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn several things about writing SQL queries.

First, always use explicit `join` syntax.  An easy rule is:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Second, you need to `join` the two tables on something.  I am guessing a field like `PublisherId`, but you might actually know the right field.

Third, `in` is much clearer than a sequence of `or` clauses.

Four, you cannot include `avg()` in  a `where` clause.  That is the purpose of the `having` clause.

Five, if you are doing an aggregation expecting multiple result rows, you need a `group by`.

```
SELECT p.NAME, b.CATEGORY, TO_CHAR(AVG(b.RETAIL), '99.99') as "Avg Retail"
FROM BOOKS b JOIN
     PUBLISHER p
     on b.PublishedId = b.PublisherId
WHERE b.category in ('CHILDREN', 'COMPUTER')
GROUP BY p.NAME, b.CATEGORY
HAVING AVG(b.RETAIL) > 50;
```

Comment: Six, (though now irrelevant because GL's query doesn't contain the mistake) you need brackets when you are mixing "and" & "or" conditions.